# Is it possible to monitor Android, Windows phone or iPhone Apps to identify what endpoint they are using

Tags: android, iphone, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

I don't know if this is possible, but as many of you know, most Smartphone applications use/communicate with a WebService.

Is it possible to know what web service address they are accessing?

I tried to gather these details by connecting the smart phone to a Wifi Network and scan the packages that were being passed. However I had no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://mitmproxy.org ?

Comment: Check out fiddler: http://fiddler2.com/